# Solutions for a system of PDE's

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $ \Omega_s(x) $ solve the system

$$s \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\Omega_s(x)=\pm x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Omega_s(x) $$

$$2\sqrt{s}\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \sqrt{\pm\Omega_s(x)}=\sqrt{x} ~\Psi \Omega.$$

where

$$\Psi \Omega := \sqrt{\mp\frac{\partial}{\partial x}{\Omega_s(x)}}$$

on some domain $D\subset\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$, with Cauchy data $\Omega_s(x)|_{s=0}.$ Assume $\Omega$ is real analytic, thus it has some holomorphic extension, $\tilde \Omega.$

By transforming the system via $s\mapsto is$ we see that $\Delta(s,x)=\tilde \Omega(is,x)$ solves

$$is \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\Delta(s,x)=\mp x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Delta(s,x) $$

and we can write down the transformed (nonlinear) equation in a similar manner.

I'm interested in the existence of solutions and any sort of structure the solutions may have, as well as uniqueness for the original and transformed system.

> What can be said?

There may only be certain solutions with no nice structure involved do to the nonlinearity of the system but I welcome any solutions at all.

Comment: There seems to exist at least one solution $\Delta(s,x)=\exp \big(\frac{\mp is}{\log x} \big)$ but it would be nice to have a more systematic approach for existence here.